# Using python bleak, bluetooth device can scan but cannot connect

Tags: python, windows, bluetooth

I have a question because there is a problem connecting the flowtime device of enterch using python's break.

I got a MAC address by scanning the terminal for Bluetooth connection.

Mac addresses are received well.

but when I tried to connect to the device using the MAC address, I couldn't find the MAC address.

What should I do in this case?

I use window10, python3.8

This is the code I used.
https://github.com/Entertech/Enter-AffectiveCloud-PC-SDK/blob/main/examples/headband_relatime_gui_demo.py

The error message is as follows

```
INFO - 2023-02-28 14:45:34,569 - enterble.collector.collector - Scanning for Flowtime Headband...
INFO - 2023-02-28 14:45:39,595 - enterble.ble.device - Device initialized: "MY MAC ADDRESS": Flowtime Headband
INFO - 2023-02-28 14:45:39,595 - enterble.collector.collector - Found "MY MAC ADDRESS": Flowtime Headband
INFO - 2023-02-28 14:45:39,596 - enterble.ble.device - Connecting to "MY MAC ADDRESS": Flowtime Headband
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/enjoy/Documents/EDU-AI/project/AiDO-LOCA/04_version2/brain wave/flowtime.py", line 145, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(data_collector())
  File "C:\Users\enjoy\.conda\envs\brain\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "c:/Users/enjoy/Documents/EDU-AI/project/AiDO-LOCA/04_version2/brain wave/flowtime.py", line 133, in data_collector
    await collector.start()
  File "C:\Users\enjoy\.conda\envs\brain\lib\site-packages\enterble\collector\collector.py", line 75, in start
    await self.device.start_notify(char_specifier, callback)
  File "C:\Users\enjoy\.conda\envs\brain\lib\site-packages\enterble\ble\device.py", line 270, in start_notify
    await (await self.client()).start_notify(char_specifier, callback)
  File "C:\Users\enjoy\.conda\envs\brain\lib\site-packages\enterble\ble\device.py", line 129, in client
    await self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\enjoy\.conda\envs\brain\lib\site-packages\enterble\ble\device.py", line 113, in connect
    await self._client.connect()
  File "C:\Users\enjoy\.conda\envs\brain\lib\site-packages\bleak\__init__.py", line 471, in connect
    return await self._backend.connect(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\enjoy\.conda\envs\brain\lib\site-packages\bleak\backends\winrt\client.py", line 239, in connect
    raise BleakDeviceNotFoundError(
bleak.exc.BleakDeviceNotFoundError: Device with address "MY MAC ADDRESS" was not found.
```

Comment: Device scan with BleakScanner is successful, but I have not been able to get a service from the BleakClient.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have a similar problem when using my bluetooth headphones at the same time as trying to connect to my device. Turning the headphones off solved the problem for me.
So it might be a good idea to check if there are other bluetooth devices that is disturbing the connection.